# Qt5: как обновить данные в QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть некоторая таблица в которую из базы данных через промежуточную структуру подгружаются данные(вектор объектов класса). В структуре данные обновляются. Как обновить значение в ячейке согласно тому, что есть в структуре?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать [qsqltablemodel](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#details)? Или создайте свою модель через QAbstractTableModel и показывайте ее через QTableView. Или в реализации с QTableWidget вручную обновляйте элементы таблицы

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю, как это можно сделать средствами `QTableWidget`. `removeItem()` почему-то не работает надлежащим образом...

Comment: Не нужно это делать с помощью `QTableWidget`, ибо для избавления от велосипедов `QTableView` (= В Qt почти каждому виджету сопоставляется свой вью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Qt есть заготовленные классы для промежуточных структур, в которые загружаются данные для отображения в таблицах, деревьях и других представлениях, в том числе определённых вами. Это называется [Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). Суть в том, что ваша "промежуточная структура" должна наследоваться от класса `QAbstractItemModel` и реализовывать его методы доступа к данным. В случае изменения каких-либо полей класс должен отправить сигнал `dataChanged`. В случае добавления-удаления строк нужно вызывать методы `beginInsertRows`, `endInsertRows`. При соединении модели с представлением методом `QTableView::setModel`, вам больше не нужно будет беспокоиться об изменениях в данных.

Кстати, для работы c таблицами из баз данных в Qt есть модель [QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#details).

Comment: Я огульно принял ответ забыв прояснить один момент. Я вас понял, но придерживаться данной рекомендации я не стану, в виду отсутствия времени на перелопачивание кода. Во второй части своей курсовой работы я учту данную вами информацию. Данный комментарий следует считать за дисклеймер.

Comment: Тогда вы можете в вашей структуре сделать сигнал обновления данных, ловить его на форме, где находится таблица, и в слоте обновлять саму таблицу.

Comment: собственно в том вопрос и заключался, как это сделать нормально, ибо структура обновляется, а данные в таблице как-то не очень. пробовал пересоздавать строки в таблице и это не работает.